# How i can make integer list with many inputs?

Tags: string, list, input, integer

I want make list with many inputs  and how i can change strings list  to  integer list . in python 3

my code

```
x= input()

while x in ('1','2','3'):
    for h in x :

        x = input()

y = list(h)
print(y)
```

run the code

```
1
2
3
4
['3']
```

it just print `['3']` i want print `['1','2','3']`
and  how i can change that to `[1,2,3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a string to an int by using the `int()` function.

The reason why it only prints ['3'] is because the for loop iterates through the current x value. Every time you iterate through the for loop there's a new h and x value. In your example the current value of x and h is '3'. Once the while loop breaks, the current value of h is converted to a list which is why you get ['3'].

A simple fix is you can initialize an empty list and add the input to that list by using the `append()` method.

```
y = [] #initialize list
x = input()
while x in ('1','2','3'):
    y.append(int(x)) #convert string to int and add to list y
    x = input()
print(y)
```

Output

```
1
2
3
4
[1, 2, 3]
```